# UWP (UAP 10.0.16299) with referenced project with .Net standard 2.0 occurs problem with LINQ (IEnumerable)

Tags: c#, linq, uwp, ienumerable

I face a problem with my UWP application.
I have the client UWP (target version is Windows 10 Fall Creator Update 10.0.16299 and same for min version ) which reference 2 other projects Net standard 2.0

I get those errors in AppShell.cs and some other Page :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

the lines where are the problem are all about link :

```
var item = (from p in PrimaryMenuItems where p.DestPage == e.SourcePageType select p).SingleOrDefault();
```

I really don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that NuGet Packages were not correctly restored. Close Visual Studio and delete all `bin` and `obj` folders in your solution. Then open your solution again and right-click on the solution in **Solution Explorer** and select **Restore NuGet Packages**. The errors should go away after that.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it s not so easy, I spent time on it, but I am still stucked, worst, I ve no explanation. Why on the IEnumerable ?? it's something really weird. If I remove the reference to my .Net Standard 2.0 projects everything becomes fine.

Comment: Just to try it out, can you add a new .NET Standard project to the solution and see if the problem happens there as well?

Comment: I guess the error message confused me, my 2 referenced projects target is Net Std 2.0, In fact, one of them is a Model project and the other a Repository project. The model project when it is referenced, doesn t occur any problem. So I am now focusing on the repository project which references : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQlite and Microsoft.Logging.Extension.Console. Maybe it comes from entity libs, I need to check

Comment: Compare the .csproj file contents to see if there are any other differences as well potentially

Comment: I made tests referencing only the Model project (.Net std 2.0) which has not references, no errors during the build, but when I start the app, I get this : Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException.   HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=Le texte associé à ce code d’erreur est introuvable.

Cannot deserialize XBF metadata type list as 'NavMenuListView' was not found in .... 
on the AppShell.cs constructor when calling InitializeComponent(). I guess there is an issue with the UAP 10.0.16299 and Net Std 2.0 compatibility. I made a previous version using .Net Std 1.3 was working, but I need to use 2

Comment: 16299 is 2.0 compatible, shouldn't cause issues. Are you sure both Target and Min version are 16299

Comment: In case you can create a simple repro and put it on GitHub, I could try it on my PC too

Comment: I solved the problem for the Model project which .Net Std 2.0 creating a new empty project and copy my classes inside, I don't really understand what was the issue. Anyway, with the DAL it s another story. I created an empty .net std 2.0 project and just add the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore nuget pckg. without adding any class. I cannot build my UWP : CS0012 The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

Comment: So need to investigate. But thanks for your help @Martin Zikmund :)

Comment: Very unusual :-O . Definitely post an update if you figure something out!

Comment: sure I will, it makes me crazy :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally after many hours, I just understood and found the solution to this tricky issue.
In my UWP project file (.csproj) , the version of the referenced Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform was 5.3.3, I replaced it by 6.1.5 and it works.